# Controlling the default language (localization) in MDriven

Tags: mdriven

I am using the [MDriven wiki](https://wiki.mdriven.net/index.php/Localization) support but would like to control the default language. Now it will revert to the original value is used. My issue is that if a browser with setting of "french" will the UI be rendered in (design language, Swedish) and not in prefered English

Answer (score 0):

You can force the default language with an `EAL` action like this :

```
'Whatever'.Translate('DEFAULT=sv-SE')
```

This was not mentioned in the [wiki](https://wiki.mdriven.net/index.php/Localization) but it is updated now.